# loop/add-to-cart.php how to add a title attribute to a tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a title attribute to a tag for accessibility and i can't seem to get it working. My code is the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop Add to Cart
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow mal" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s"><span>%s</span></a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop Add to Cart
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow mal" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" title="%s" class="%s"><span>%s</span></a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_title() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

Comment: Please use this updated code i have added the title attribute in it.

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but doesn't seem to work. I don't know what's going on. Do you suggest anything else please?

Comment: A follow up is that whatever change i do to this file in my child theme doesn't do it, i even removed the entire a tag and it displayed it like it still there, i have cleared the cache many times delete cookies and everything. Do you have any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Hi @ChrisGrizis, Are you doing template override?

if yes, then you should double check if override works properly.

Follow this : Copy the template into a directory within your child-theme named /woocommerce keeping the same file structure but removing the /templates/ subdirectory & then make the changes in the same file.

Comment: Hi @Deepak Kumar Dass, Yes i am doing it right my override on theme and child theme is woocomerce/loop/add-to-cart.php.

Comment: And i have checked again in woocommerce conditions and it's seem the override of templates i have overridden is correct from the child-theme and has woocommerce  theme support. Is there i have tried to add the title attribute via js and didn't work either.